# How to Simplify Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, hibernate-annotations

I am using @NotEmpty annotation from Hibernate validator. However I am required to provide custom message. Thus I am trying the following in order to eliminate duplicate code

```
@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty
public @interface NotEmpty {
    String message() default "{notempty}";
}
```

Is above the right way to do that ? May I know what's the term of this annotation overriding ?

Comment: If you have to provide defualt message change the value of key `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message` there is no need to have another annotation. Also this is defualt message you can anyways specify message while declaring annotion.

Comment: I have added the key in both of my ValidationMessages.properties files and it works like a charm. Just to clarify, is there a way to make my above annotation works ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide default message change the value of key `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message` inside `ValidationMessages.properties` there is no need to have another annotation. Also this is defualt message you can anyways specify message while declaring annotion

You can read more about anotations on [Annotation Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html)